# vb.net Array.copy doesn't leave destination buffer at expected size

Tags: .net, vb.net

I allocate the source buffer and the destin buffer...

> dim packet_receive_buffer( 4104 ) as Byte
>    dim payload_buffer( 4104 )
>   as Byte

I Fill packet_receive_buffer with 4100 bytes…

> USB_Interface.receive_async(  packet_receive_buffer,
>                                 bytes_to_read,
>                                 total_transferred_bytes )

( bytes_to_read and total_transferred_bytes are both = 4100 )

I Copy to payload_buffer 4096 bytes from packet_receive_buffer, skipping the first 4 bytes of packet_receive_buffer ……..

> Array.Copy( packet_receive_buffer, 4,                 payload_buffer, 0, 
>   bytes_to_read - 4)

ERROR…  the payload_buffer array size is 4105 instead of 4096.

Comment: You can always dimension your `payload_buffer` to the bytes actually read minus the section you don't care about, then perform the copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying an array does not change its size. What `Array.Copy` does is to replace the values from the specified start index through the specified stop index with the values from the new array.

In your code, you made the following declarations

```
Dim packet_receive_buffer(4104) as Byte
Dim payload_buffer(4104) as Byte
```

That initialized the `packet_receive_buffer` array to 4105 bytes. To actually get 4096 bytes, you should declare it like this

```
Dim packet_receive_buffer(4095) as Byte
```

Note that a byte array declared as `byte(x)` allocates `x + 1` spaces for storage. This can be seen using `GC.GetTotalMemory`.